# Is ASP.NET razor run locally?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, localization

Currently I'm working on a global time localisation project, with a database stored as UTC I need to filter by date-time on the front-end

```
@{ foreach(var financialTransaction in Model.FinancialTransactionRows)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

From my understanding of the DateTime class the time data is gathered from the local system. However, if I add the following Razor:

```
@{ foreach(var financialTransaction in Model.FinancialTransactionRows.Where(ft => ft.CreatedDateTime < DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime())
 {
      //Do stuff
 }
```

Is this going to be the local time in regards to the servers location or the users'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razor is *typically* part of the server-side processing, so it would be the server time. You *can use* razor outside of a web-server though - so now I'm having images of razor hosted via blazor / web-assembly in a browser. That's a horrible image :)

But: if you're just doing "normal things": this is strictly server-side. As a side note: you should *usually hope* that folks *roughly* agree on `DateTime.UtcNow` (barring a clock that is simply wrong); it is `DateTime.Now` that gets *significantly* different based on the locale.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, javascript here I come